# Where is my EFI? Dual booting arch linux and windows 8.1

Tags: linux, partitioning, windows-8.1, ssd, multi-boot

I will start by saying I have never used UEFI before and am still trying to understand.

So I have a 120GB SSD and a 1TB HDD.

Formated In this way.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V28Rx.png]

Windows 8 is installed as C: and I want to install ArchLinux on the EXT4 partition. What I am confused about is the fact that it seems that my EFI partition is on my HDD yet I am currently booting windows off my SSD. How is this possible and why would windows do this? How can I get Grub to recognize where my EFI partition is and use it?

Comment: Have you turned off "Fast boot ?"

Comment: Also, when I dual-boot, I made a Grub partition. I think i disabled the EFI boot option.